# Qual a diferença entre stack frame e execution context? São a mesma coisa em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, stack

Estou tentando me aprofundar no funcionamento do javascript e estou com dúvidas entre algumas definições que encontrei.
Primeiramente, uma representação simplificada do ambiente de execução do javascript no browser seria essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comecei a estudar sobre a pilha de chamdas do JavaScript(Call stack) e encontrei uma definição que diz:

> Uma call stack(pilha de chamadas) é **formada por 1 ou mais stack
>   frames**. Um stack frame é adicionado/empilhado na call stack
>   toda vez que uma função é chamada.

A representação seria essa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até esse ponto consegui entender, porém me deparei com uma definição um pouco diferente dizendo que:

> Uma call stack é uma **coleção de execution contexts**(contextos de
>   execução) e que um contexto de execução é criado e empihado quando uma
>   função é chamada.

Já vi até mesmo chamarem a call stack de execution stack.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essas definições representam a mesma estrutura em JavaScript ou são Stacks diferentes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A informação é um pouco falha. Ela não está errada, até é isto mesmo, mas "contexto de execução" é algo mais amplo. Existem vários contextos de execução, que de certa forma podemos chamar de escopo (não sei se é exatamente a mesma coisa porque esse termo é usado mais em JS mesmo). Existe o contexto de execução global e os locais que são das funções, e o *stack frame* se confunde com um contexto de execução já que uma função tem seu próprio contexto de execução.

Me parece errado esse *global stack frame* porque essa informação não pode ser empilhada, ela precisa estar em uma área não estruturada, como um *heap* e não um *stack*.

Pelo que entendo *stack frame* é usado de forma mais concreta de como é implementado e *execution context* é usado como conceito mais abstrato.

Então acho que é só uma questão de terminologia diferente olhando níveis de abstração diferentes.