# Estado de registrador em calling covention

Tags: assembly, stack, arquitetura-computadores

Na *calling convention* da ABI, o prólogo de início de uma nova pilha faz, por padrão, um `push EBP`. Até então tudo bem, mas por que fazer `mov EBP, ESP` se `ESP` já está "apontando" pro topo, que - no caso - seria o valor de `EBP` salvo na pilha após o `push`?

Quando "faço" `push EBP`, o `ESP` não já está "apontando" pro `EBP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta deveria ser oposta. Por que fazer um `push EBP` se não vai mexer no registrador `EBP`?

A instrução `push` coloca o valor do registrador na pilha para em determinando momento poder recuperar o valor que está lá de volta para o registrador. Desta forma você pode usar esse registrador à vontade e mudar seus valores o quanto quiser sem se preocupar, já que o valor original está preservado, então em determinado momento (nesse caso no epílogo da função) haverá um `pop EBP` para restaurar o valor do topo da pilha para o registrador. Então se fizer isso e não mudar o valor do `EBP` está desperdiçando uma instrução ali, e possivelmente outra quando der o `pop`.

Ele fez porque logo em seguida mudará o valor do `EBP`.

> ESP já está apontando pro topo

`ESP` é o registrador Stack Pointer (estendido), portanto ele aponta para o topo da pilha. Nesse momento a pilha está no fim do *stack frame* anterior, a parte que está reservada para as variáveis da função anterior. Então certamente `EBP` e `ESP` não estão com mesmo valor, você tem que colocar o novo valor de `EBP` baseando-se no valor de `ESP`.

`EBP` é o registrador Base Pointer (estendido), portanto ele aponta para a base do *stack frame* atual, que no momento que entra em uma função, antes de executar o prólogo, o valor é a base da função anterior.

Então essa operação está fazendo com o que o `EBP` tenha um novo começo.

O que deve estar te confundindo é porque não viu uma instrução mudar o `ESP`, e de fato não costuma-se fazer isso, outras instruções é que o fazem como parte de sua operação. As mais óbvias são as instruções `push` e `pop` que obviamente muda o valor toda vez que coloca ou tira algo da pilha. Então essas instruções vão mudando `ESP`, mas o `EBP` só é mudado manualmente, por isso eles só são iguais quando você move o valor de um para o outro, logo depois de ter qualquer instrução que mexe o `ESP`, já não será mais.

[image: Composição da pilha na chamada]

> Quando "faço" push EBP, o ESP não já está "apontando" pro EBP?

Sua conclusão que topo da pilha e base do *stack frame* anterior são a mesma coisa está equivocada.

Pode ajudar:

- [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre stack frame e execution context? São a mesma coisa em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/377841/101)
- [Quando ocorre Stack Overflow?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101)
- [Como funciona o frame-pointer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184498/101)
- [Variáveis declaradas dentro de blocos ou subprogramas são alocadas dinamicamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/280973/101)
- [Como funciona a C99 em relação à C90 para declaração de variáveis no meio do código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48231/101)

Comment: excelente! Mt obgd